# Issues in passing parameters to Jasper Reports

Tags: java, mysql, sql, parameters, jasper-reports

I am trying to pass 2 parameters into Jasper report and get the result. In SQL query, I am combining them with the query as below.

```
SELECT 
ROUND(SUM(case when Updated_Date BETWEEN $P{secondYear}+"-03-01" AND $P{secondYear}+"-03-31" then Amount else 0 end),2) AS `March` ,
ROUND(SUM(case when Updated_Date BETWEEN $P{secondYear}+"-02-01" AND $P{secondYear}+"-02-29" then Amount else 0 end),2) AS `February` ,
ROUND(SUM(case when Updated_Date BETWEEN $P{secondYear}+"-01-01" AND $P{secondYear}+"-01-31" then Amount else 0 end),2) AS `January` ,
ROUND(SUM(case when Updated_Date BETWEEN $P{firstYear}+"-12-01" AND $P{firstYear}+"-12-31" then Amount else 0 end),2) AS `December` ,
ROUND(SUM(case when Updated_Date BETWEEN $P{firstYear}+"-11-01" AND $P{firstYear}+"-11-31" then Amount else 0 end),2) AS `November` ,
ROUND(SUM(case when Updated_Date BETWEEN $P{firstYear}+"-10-01" AND $P{firstYear}+"-10-31" then Amount else 0 end),2) AS `October` ,
ROUND(SUM(case when Updated_Date BETWEEN $P{firstYear}+"-09-01" AND $P{firstYear}+"-09-31" then Amount else 0 end),2) AS `September` ,
ROUND(SUM(case when Updated_Date BETWEEN $P{firstYear}+"-08-01" AND $P{firstYear}+"-08-31" then Amount else 0 end),2) AS `August` ,
ROUND(SUM(case when Updated_Date BETWEEN $P{firstYear}+"-07-01" AND $P{firstYear}+"-07-31" then Amount else 0 end),2) AS `July` ,
ROUND(SUM(case when Updated_Date BETWEEN $P{firstYear}+"-06-01" AND $P{firstYear}+"-06-31" then Amount else 0 end),2) AS `June`, 
ROUND(SUM(case when Updated_Date BETWEEN $P{firstYear}+"-05-01" AND $P{firstYear}+"-05-31" then Amount else 0 end),2) AS `May`,
ROUND(SUM(case when Updated_Date BETWEEN $P{firstYear}+"-04-01" AND $P{firstYear}+"-04-31" then Amount else 0 end),2) AS `April` 
FROM VAT
```

However, In my Jasper report, what I get is 0 as the VAT for all the months, all the time. What have I done wrong?

Comment: You need to provide some more details. How are you passing the parameters in your code? How are the parameters defined in the JRXML?

Comment: @jschoen: I still didn't move to the code. Passing parameters via Jaspersoft studio. The query above is the original one I use inside jasper.

Comment: I am not as familiar with Jaspersoft studio, but I know with ireport when you went to preview it would prompt you for the parameter values. Do you get something like that? If not you can set the default values for each parameter to what you want to try it with and see what happens.

Comment: @jschoen: Yes, that prompt came in.

Comment: How sure are you the query is correct? If you replaced the parameters parts with the just hard coded values do you get what you would expect?

Comment: @jschoen: Hi, I found the answer. I made a post below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. In jasper report, if you want to combine `parameters` like `String` in your SQL Query, you should not use the `+` sign. So the correct code is below.

```
SELECT 
ROUND(SUM(case when Updated_Date BETWEEN $P{secondYear}"-03-01" AND $P{secondYear}"-03-31" then Amount else 0 end),2) AS `March` ,
ROUND(SUM(case when Updated_Date BETWEEN $P{secondYear}"-02-01" AND $P{secondYear}"-02-29" then Amount else 0 end),2) AS `February` ,
ROUND(SUM(case when Updated_Date BETWEEN $P{secondYear}"-01-01" AND $P{secondYear}"-01-31" then Amount else 0 end),2) AS `January` ,
ROUND(SUM(case when Updated_Date BETWEEN $P{firstYear}"-12-01" AND $P{firstYear}"-12-31" then Amount else 0 end),2) AS `December` ,
ROUND(SUM(case when Updated_Date BETWEEN $P{firstYear}"-11-01" AND $P{firstYear}"-11-31" then Amount else 0 end),2) AS `November` ,
ROUND(SUM(case when Updated_Date BETWEEN $P{firstYear}"-10-01" AND $P{firstYear}"-10-31" then Amount else 0 end),2) AS `October` ,
ROUND(SUM(case when Updated_Date BETWEEN $P{firstYear}"-09-01" AND $P{firstYear}"-09-31" then Amount else 0 end),2) AS `September` ,
ROUND(SUM(case when Updated_Date BETWEEN $P{firstYear}"-08-01" AND $P{firstYear}"-08-31" then Amount else 0 end),2) AS `August` ,
ROUND(SUM(case when Updated_Date BETWEEN $P{firstYear}"-07-01" AND $P{firstYear}"-07-31" then Amount else 0 end),2) AS `July` ,
ROUND(SUM(case when Updated_Date BETWEEN $P{firstYear}"-06-01" AND $P{firstYear}"-06-31" then Amount else 0 end),2) AS `June`, 
ROUND(SUM(case when Updated_Date BETWEEN $P{firstYear}"-05-01" AND $P{firstYear}"-05-31" then Amount else 0 end),2) AS `May`,
ROUND(SUM(case when Updated_Date BETWEEN $P{firstYear}"-04-01" AND $P{firstYear}"-04-31" then Amount else 0 end),2) AS `April` 
FROM VAT
```

If you are using Jaspersoft Studio, it will display this as an error in Query editor. However, it works with no issues.